# Autocomplete off on Angular Directive for Date Picker

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a directive for JQuery Date picker which injects date picker into input HTML control. This was developed by a previous developer and I am pretty new to Angular at this moment.

My question is that is there any way to prevent showing auto complete on all the date pickers that we inject via this directive?

```
export class DanialDatePickerDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

    constructor(protected el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    @Input() dateformat: string = "DD-MMM-YY";
    @Input() ngModel: any;
    @Input() setDefaultDate: boolean;
    onModelChange: Function = () => { };
    onModelTouched: Function = () => { };

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value) {
            var ff = new Date(value);
            $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker("setDate", ff);
        }
        else {
            $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker("setDate", "");
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelTouched = fn;
    }

    onBlur() {
        this.onModelTouched();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var self = this;
        $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-y',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });

        if (this.setDefaultDate) {
            var ff = new Date(self.ngModel);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(self.el.nativeElement).datepicker("setDate", ff);
            }, 200);
        }

        $(this.el.nativeElement).on('change', (e: any) => {
            var model = e.target.value;
            var date = null;
            var monthstring = '';
            if (model.indexOf("-") > 0){
                monthstring = model.substring(model.indexOf("-") + 1, 5);
            }

            if (isNaN(parseInt(monthstring))) { 
                var tt = moment(model, "DD-MMM-YY").format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                date = tt;
                model = moment(model, "DD-MMM-YYYY").format('MM-DD-YYYY') 
            }
            else {

                date = moment(model, "DD-MM-YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                model = moment(model, "DD-MM-YYYY").format('MM-DD-YYYY') 
            }

            $(".ui-datepicker a").removeAttr("href"); 
            self.onModelChange(date);

             self.writeValue(date.toString());
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Apparantly it is not so much of an Angular problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 2):

The only approach who works for me:

First, make sure to set `autocomplete="off"` on both, the input element itself and the parent form.

Second, make sure to assign an unique name to your input field always.
This can be achieved by simply generating a random number and using this number in the name of the field.

```
  private getUniqueName() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Date.now());
  }
```

Explanation:

> In the past, many developers would add autocomplete="off" to their
>   form fields to prevent the browser from performing any kind of
>   autocomplete functionality. While Chrome will still respect this tag
>   for autocomplete data, it will not respect it for autofill data.
>   https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill.

So `autocomplete="off"` solves the autocomplete issue. But to solve the autofill you need to play dirty with the browser by changing the name of the input over an over again, that way the browser will never know how to autofill ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it screw up the functionality? I mean If we have mix codes with Jquery and Angular etc.?

Comment: To be fair, I'd suggest to take another approach for your DatePicker component, one with no jQuery dependencies. There's a lot of DatePickers on npmjs ready to use and Angular ready.

Comment: Problem is this is a legacy system, and a lot of developers are working on the same. Scrapping what we have now entirely is not possible I guess. Also my task is low in story points.

Comment: Go for the autocomplete="off" approach first. The functionality of the DatePicker will remain the same :)

Comment: In the case of the parent form, yes. For the the input tag you can use an @Input as a flag to set "autocomplete=off" or not. Same for the <input name="date_00398387472"> trick.